# Arduino code: Color Detection using IR sensor

Tags: arduino

I have a question in my textbook which says to write an arduino code by means of which an IRSensor can be used to identify black and white colors. I have searched everywhere on the net and have not found a solution. Can someone help me in this code?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found these links in my first google search:
 - http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=143767.0
 - http://www.instructables.com/id/Multi-Function-Automatic-Move-Smart-Car-for-Arduin/step11/Black-or-white-line-detection-principle/

These should help you get started in thinking about how to code for this but also leaves room for you to think about the right answer on your own. If you need help with the actual coding part, edit your question with your code and whatever errors you are having trouble with.